# Infopath Multiple-Selection list's Item Changed Event is not working in web browser

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have an infopath form applied to a Form Library in my sharepoint site which have managed code. In that form I use a Multiple-Selection list in a section that shows items (documents) from a Sharepoint Document library through REST service. When I check the document item in the Multiple-Selection list, the changed event (XmlChangedEventHandler) in the managed code manipulated the item checked. Here is the Code:

```
 public void Documents_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
    {               
    string docId = e.Site.Value;
    }
```

Everything works fine in InfoPath form preview, but when I pubished that to the sharepoint form library, I am not able to get the value for docId. The "e.Site.Value" is getting null.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Myself found a work around for this. Avoided relying on the e.Site.Value and brought a new Button under the the Multiple-Selection list. Thus handled my business case. But I am still looking for a good answer for this question